# Broken User Registration Form in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, forms, ruby-2.3

I'm having an issue with my user registration form in Ruby on Rails.
I had it working before simply with just a username, email, and password. However when I tried to add fields for first name, last name, and ZIP code, it stopped inserting any data into the database, and just redirects back to the registration form.

I did it the correct way with generating migrations and migrating the db- the form still wasn't working.

I then dropped the database entirely and recreated it with all of the fields included, and it still won't work. The database was generated correctly with the correct fields, and I'm not sure where the disconnect is.

I'm using ruby 2.3.1.

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create 
  @user = User.new(user_params) 
  if @user.save 
    session[:user_id] = @user.id 
    redirect_to '/home' 
  else 
    redirect_to '/register' 
  end 
end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :location, :fname, :lname)
  end

end
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    has_secure_password 

end
```

Form at users/new:

```
  <div class="container">      
  </div>

<div id="contact" class="container-fluid bg-grey">

  <h2 class="text-center">Create An Account</h2>
  <form>

        <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :username, :placeholder => "Username" %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %><br/><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :fname, :placeholder => "First Name" %>
        <%= f.text_field :lname, :placeholder => "Last Name" %>
        <%= f.number_field :location, :placeholder => "ZIP Code (US Only)" %><br/><br/>
      <%= f.submit "Create an Account", class: "btn-submit" %>
    <% end %>

</div>

 </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Create users migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.numeric :location
      t.string :fname
      t.string :lname

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

From log:

```
 Started GET "/register?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=b6M1gpQx8BTLhBqjjh6R%2BlSGghcSh18Mg7eGskLGNyq11RBvGCX%2BOJjVhSLwwRmZunn1sYvV4MGHB7vrJw6Rhg%3D%3D&user%5Busername%5D=jsmith1&user%5Bemail%5D=jsmith%40email.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=[FILTERED]&user%5Bfname%5D=John&user%5Blname%5D=Smith&user%5Blocation%5D=60606&commit=Create+an+Account" for ::1 at 2016-11-07 15:14:50 -0600
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"b6M1gpQx8BTLhBqjjh6R+lSGghcSh18Mg7eGskLGNyq11RBvGCX+OJjVhSLwwRmZunn1sYvV4MGHB7vrJw6Rhg==", "user"=>{"username"=>"jsmith1", "email"=>"jsmith@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "fname"=>"John", "lname"=>"Smith", "location"=>"60606"}, "commit"=>"Create an Account"}
  Rendering users/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 195ms (Views: 148.1ms | ActiveRecord: 21.5ms)

)
    Completed 200 OK in 760ms (Views: 714.8ms | ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)
```

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Unfortunately, "it stopped working" lacks sufficient technical detail to provide help. Is there some error? What actually happens? Make things easier on the people helping you by skipping the big guessing game about what is actually wrong by simply telling us up front.

Comment: can you post server log?

Comment: Sorry. It won't save the user and insert the data into the database, it just goes back to the registration form.

Comment: Replace `if @user.save ` with `if @user.save! ` and try it again. Tell us what the console/log says.

Comment: Added it at the bottom, MarsAtomic

Comment: See that 200 status? That means OK. If you look in your database, is the user created or not? Also, if you want to get the attention of a specific user, type @ followed by the username so they'll see a notification in their title bar. Otherwise, you're relying on them to manually check your question, which may or may not happen.

Comment: @MarsAtomic It is not. I just double checked my database.yml file and it's the correct database, the table exists with all of the columns, but no information is actually being inserted in the database. And thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The extra form tag was messing with the form submission. Once I removed `<form>` from above the Ruby form code, it worked. Thank you to the people who responded.